# agGrid: how to disable hiding ungroupable columns after dragging them to the row group panel?

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have an angular application that I am adding an agGrid table to. I configured the table to allow grouping rows as follows:

```
  <ag-grid-angular
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [rowData]="activeMethods"
    [groupDefaultExpanded]="-1"
    [rowGroupPanelShow]="'always'"
  >
  </ag-grid-angular>
```

And I set some of the columns to be groupable as follows:

```
    enableRowGroup: true,
    enablePivot: true,
```

This shows the row group panel and allows grouping of the columns I drag into it, but the issue is that "non-groupable" columns that I drag into the panel are hidden. I need those columns not to be hidden when dragged there. I know that the `suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns` parameter disables hiding any column when it's dragged away from the table, but I would want the "groupable" columns to still be hidden when dragged to the group panel. Is what I want to achieve easily doable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could keep `suppressDragLeaveHidesColumns` to prevent the non grouping columns to be hidden when dragged outside the grid, and then leverage the Grid Event `columnRowGroupChanged` to change the column that is being grouped, to be hidden. You can find the [documentation for this here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#reference-columns).

In Version 24, this can be easily achieved using the Column API method `applyColumnState`, documentation on [this can be found here](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-column-state/)

Putting this all together:

```
  onColumnRowGroupChanged(params) {
    let columnStateParams = [];

    params.columns.forEach(col => {
      columnStateParams.push({ colId: col.getColId(), hide: true });
    });

    params.columnApi.applyColumnState({
      state: columnStateParams,
    });
  }
```

I've created a [Plunker showing this](https://plnkr.co/edit/jalX9z6jXf2ZsN8B?preview)

The Year and Country column can be grouped only, the Athlete and Age columns cannot be grouped.

Comment: Great answer! Thanks